# Authenticated email reply

Tags: email, cryptography

How does reply.github.com work? I've noticed you can reply to Github emails, for example:

```
Reply-To: example/foobar <reply+000bafafcb72e8dc89884bda7ce639d101cc16b69010bcaa92cf0000000117ad897992a169ce14271668@reply.github.com>
X-Auto-Response-Suppress: All
```

reply+${84_chars}@reply.github.com

And that is enough to append your message:

1. particular Github issue
2. in your name or userID

My question is, what encoding is that?

It's not HMAC as I believe you need to send your unecrypted message with that encoding.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about reverse-engineering GitHub URLs, not programming. You could perhaps try asking at [reverseengineering.stackexchange.com](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/), but please check first to make sure it is on-topic there.

Answer (score 0):

HMAC was the answer after all. There was no need to hide the data I was trying to validate. The message authentication code (MAC) becomes a signature component which I verify in my backend.

```
const crypto = require('crypto')

const secret = process.env.API_ACCESS_TOKEN

function genreply (bugID, secret) {
  const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret)
    .update(bugID)
    .digest('hex')

  return `reply+${bugID}-${hash}@example.com`
}

console.log(genreply('61825', secret))
```